# Where can I find 1.5kWh energy, at about 5-15Wh/kg batteries that can deliver about 350kW power? (as indicated on this wikipedia article?)

Tags: batteries, power-electronics, automotive, supercapacitor, high-power

I am a rookie in this field, so any kind of feedback/edit is welcome! :)

I am currently trying to find supercapacitors/batteries that have following properties:

1. Have about 1.5kWh energy, at about 5-15Wh/kg (assuming we can stack these up to about 150kg of batteries/supercaps).
2. The power delivered must be about 350kW, so a little more than 2kW/kg.

I have read on wikipedia that they exist: [as indicated here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercapacitor#Specific_energy_and_specific_power), but I can't find these (with the respective power densities). What type of supercapacitors are these and where could I possibly contact someone who knows about this stuff? (a company selling those might be useful I guess?).

Additionally, it would be great if these could operate in near-vacuum (800-1600Pascal), but I realise that this sounds unreasonable, but I would be really grateful if you could provide me with information :)

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Hi immibis, i've replaced the link, thank you for the hint!

Comment: No luck with the table of companies right below that section on WP?   And all the company links in the refs at the end?   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercapacitor#Comparison_of_technical_parameters

Comment: @wbeaty unfortunately that doesn't give us any information on power density :/

Comment: Unfortunately there probably isn't a quicker way to do it than to find a bunch of supercapacitor products, and find out the power density of each one.

Comment: It's going to be very expensive, and rather "lively" at that kind of power level. You could probably just ring up your local electronics distributor and ask..

Comment: Inquiring minds want to know [tm] - what's the application?

Comment: Electric-turbopump motors?

Comment: Wast't QUITE fast enough to answer, dammit... In comment format, Lithium Titanate. Take a look at http://www.scib.jp/en/product/cell.htm and do the math yourself. I make it 833 cells, 125kg. Hate it when that happens.

Comment: | unfortunately that doesn't give us any...   TABLE OF COMPANIES.   COMPANY LINKS.  It's a list of supercapacitor companies.  I'd start by checking spec sheets for Maxwell Boostcaps, widely used as regenerative braking in electric vehicles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These nominally fall somewhat short of your spec on mass, exceed it on discharge power, probably exceed unstated cost spec by an order or few of magnitude (unless $ is less relevant than is likely.)

You need 500 of them at about $US60 each (!)
That just meets the energy stored spec when fully drained -  so how much you get is application dependant.
( eg discharge to 1/2 V = 75% of energy available).

[Eaton PowerStor XL60 Series 2.7V Supercapacitor cells](http://www.cooperindustries.com/content/dam/public/bussmann/Electronics/Resources/product-datasheets/bus-elx-ds-10339-xl.pdf)

3000F
2.7V max wkg
2400 A max current
3 Wh stored (total capacity)
0.525 kg

> 5-15Wh/kg

Wh/kg = 3/0.525 = 5.7 Wh/kg
Just!

1500 Wh/3 = 500 units

Assume all paralleled (! :-) ) just for figuring).
Presumably "some other topology would be employed"  [tm]

> The power delivered must be about 350kW, so a little more than 2kW/kg.

350 kW requires current at say 2.5V of 140,000 A (stand clear).
500 caps  x 2400 A = 1,200,000 A
No problemo

Or, 2 kW/kg for 0.525 kg cap
= 2 x 0.525 = 1.05 kW/cap
1050W / 2400A discharge = 0.44V.
ie this spec, unlike most others , is env\couraging.
IF you can work out how to get 2400A at Vmax/2 then
Power = 2.7V /2 x 2400 = 3.24 kW = 3+ times more than needed.
As cap has 25% of energy remaining at Vmax/2 then power delivery is probably achievable "across the range".
Energy per mass, "rather less so".

That data sheet is as at October 2014.
A lot can happen in this sort of area in that time.
**IF** $ are not a total turnoff then a talk to [**the people at Eaton**](http://www.eaton.com/Eaton/ProductsServices/Electrical/index.htm)  may be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

I'd give a look at high discharge rate lithium ion batteries. Batteries intended for radio controlled models are perhaps the most practical source for a one-off prototype; they feature massive discharge rates, moderately high energy densities and they are relatively affordable.

For example, a 22.2 V 0.864 kg pack of six 5 Ah 3.7 V pouch cells in series can be bought online for about $70. The pack has a 60 C continous discharge rating, meaning that you could draw 5 Ah * 60 = 300 A of current, equating to a power output of 300 A * 22.2 V = 6.66 kW.
Assembling 60 such packs together would yield a battery with a maximum continous power output of 400 kW, an energy storage capacity of 6.66 kWh, a mass of 52 kg and a cost of $4200. You would also require a custom battery management system, and a way to quickly run away when it blows up.